# VsCode: Is there a keyboard shortcut How to make VS Code treat files without extension as a certain language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Is there a keyboard shortcut How to make VS Code treat/reopen/reload files without extension as a certain language?

Just to be clear, here's my use case:

Sometimes I have a big JSON I need to read so I copy it in VsCode new file but since it's a new file I have to save it a s JSON extension to read it in the correct format. So my question is: Is there a way to specify the language for this new file(without extension) to open it as JSON  for example?

Thank you

Comment: Er... You don't have to save it, just change the language mode by clicking on the status bar element or invoking the Change Language Mode command (Ctrl + K, M on Windows). (Auto-detection works nicely but I guess not in this case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys I found it:
The feature is called [Change Language Mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings).

The default shortcut is `Ctrl+K M` if you want to customize it here's the name of the command:

```
workbench.action.editor.changeLanguageMode
```

You can also click in the lower right of VSCODE window to change the language mode:

[image: Change Language Mode in vscode]

Answer (score 0):

I found these two options:

```json
// The following example associates all files in a folder `somefolder` to PHP:
"files.associations": {
    "**/somefolder/*.*": "php"
}
```

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_can-i-map-additional-file-extensions-to-a-language

```json
// The default language mode that is assigned to new files.
  "files.defaultLanguage": "html"
```

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_how-do-i-set-the-default-language-for-new-files

Add the lines of your choice to `settings.json`.